# DRF: Do DRF serializers, SerializerMethodField have execution order

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class ProfileAPI(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    age = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return "name"

    def age(self,obj):
        return 78
```

is there ordering while execution of SerilaizerMethodField or it is random, means will "get_name" is executed before "get_age".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution ordering goes by the order of fields in meta.

```
class ProfileAPI(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    age = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return "name"

    def age(self,obj):
        return 78

    class Meta:
        fields = ["name", "age"]
```

In the above case "get_name" is called first and then "get_age".

---

changing the order to

```
class Meta:
     fields = ["age", "name"]
```

would execute get_age first.

Comment: Execution also matters how the fields are declared (found via experimentation). In the above case, to make `get_age` execute first, one needs to declare `age = serializers.SerializerMethodField()` before `name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()`